# Concourse CI git clone multiple repos to same directory

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline

Can someone help me to achieve my request. I would like to git clone multiple repos into the same directory where the first git repo is downloaded. Below is my `pipeline.yml` file. Any help is much appreciated.

```
resources:
- name: workspace-repo1
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <git-repo1-url>
    branch: master
    private_key: ((publishing-outputs-private-key))
- name: workspace-repo2
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <git-repo2-url>
    branch: master
    private_key: ((publishing-outputs-private-key))
- name: workspace-repo3
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <git-repo3-url>
    branch: master
    private_key: ((publishing-outputs-private-key))

jobs:
  - name: job-test
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: workspace-repo1
      - get: workspace-repo2
      - get: workspace-repo3
      - task: app-tests
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source: {repository: golang, tag: 1.14.15-stretch}
          inputs:
          - name: workspace-repo1 (git repo1, repo2,repo3 should be downloaded here)
          outputs:
          - name: workspace-repo-deb

          run:
            path: workspace-repo1/local_build.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do something like

```
  - task: prep
    file: scripts/merge.yml
    input_mapping: {repo1: workspace-1, repo1: workspace-2, ...}
```

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: alpine

params:
#this could whatever path you want
  SRC_PATH: src


inputs:
- name: ci-scripts
- name: repo1
- name: repo2

run:
  path: scripts/merge.sh

#this output could be use in the next step, it contains the directories you copied in the script below
outputs:
- name: build
```

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

mkdir -p build
#copy around anything you need 
cp -rf repo1/../../. build/
cp -rf repo2/../../. build/
cp -rf repo3/../../. build/

#listing content of build folder just checking
ls -la build/
```